# Permissions Value Sharepoint

Tags: 2007, permissions

I have two site collections existing in two different web applications. I am the site collection administrator of both.

I have created an HTML file which is placed in the layouts folder and uses the SPServices jQuery application to execute GetRolesAndPermissionsForCurrentUser.

In one of the site collections when I run I get:

```
<Permissions value = "9223372036854775807"/>
```

Which is true and means I have Full Control.

If I try the same script in the other web application I get:

```
<Permissions value = "4611688150878591999"/>
```

I really do not understand what this value means.

The reason why I was trying this is because in SharePoint Designer I am not able to open the site with:

```
<Permissions value = "4611688150878591999"/>
```

Can somebody let me know why I see this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the Why this permission value

```
<Permissions value = "4611688150878591999"/>
```

If we alter the permission level of Web Application in Central Administration . If we uncheck some values and check all the levels again sharepoint does not put the `<Permissions value = "9223372036854775807"/>`  back again it does put the

```
<Permissions value = "4611688150878591999"/>
```

A detailed post is here [link text](http://www.cjvandyk.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=744536f4-127e-4c4a-bcff-b85408e7e7e5&ID=225)

And these was not the reason for Sharepoint Designer behaviour absurd. This was because there was an httpmodule configured for 301 redirects. Now when i removed this module . I was able to access the Sharepoint Designer again